# How to Roll back Committed data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

yesterday i have removed data from my tables. I want to rollback those data. If i try with Flashback query i am getting below error.

```
ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 6 with name "_SYSSMU6_250785514$" too small
```

Query :

> SELECT * FROM CUS_ADDRESS AS OF TIMESTAMP    TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-07-10
>   11:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');

Please help me how to rollback the data.

Many thanks for your help.

I am using Oracle 11g version.

Comment: What's you `undo_retention` time? Is it guaranteed? And obviously, what's your `DB_FLASHBACK_RETENTION_TARGET` time?

Comment: Means timestamp? time stamp is " 2017-07-10 11.30.30 PM"

Comment: You are trying to flashback to the point-in-time where there is no undo records to form those deleted records.

Comment: You could try to include the time in your flashback query, just before you think you deleted the data. But if that is also outside your flashback retention period then... have you got a backup? (Also 'rollback' means something specific, you can't roll back past a commit, so you're trying to recover or restore the data...)

Comment: I guess you could try [`flashback table`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_9012.htm) with the `rename` option, but very carefully - you don't want to do any more damage to your current table - but that probably won't work for you either. That or `rman` recovery should be done by your DBA though really, if you have one. I suggest you seek advice from them.

Comment: In any case, even if you are able to restore the data you deleted, what you are doing is not a `rollback`. `rollback` is a technical word with a very specific meaning - and you can't do it anymore, if you committed the `delete` operations already.